# How do WebRTC peers connect to each other if none have opened ports?

Tags: networking, webrtc, p2p

I know there needs to be a STUN/ICE/TURN server to find the IP addresses of the peers involved in a WebRTC communication. However, even after IPs are found, how do the peers actually talk to each other independently without having any ports opened?

If you build a website, you usually have to open the ports on your server to have others access your site. What's the magic that is happening in WebRTC that I'm not understanding?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several strategies to do this: one possibility is for the client to explicitly open a port via [UPnP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play). I'm not sure if any current WebRTC client does so, but in general networking this is a possibility.

Failing that, the STUN server kicks in. There are several [hole punching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_punching_(networking)) techniques it can try; read the aforelinked article for the gory details. In short though, a firewall will usually open a port for *outgoing* traffic (because it needs to receive responses), so by establishing an outgoing connection to a known target and then making note of the port that was opened it is possible to open a port.

Failing even that, a TURN server is necessary. This server is publicly accessible from both peers, even if both peers cannot see each other. The TURN server then will act as a relay between the two. This somewhat negates the point of a P2P protocol, but is necessary in a certain percentage of situations (estimates range around 10%-20%).

Comment: Interesting. So when I access a website, my router automatically opens a  temporary port to receive the response? And all a STUN server does is figure out the port/IP that was opened and uses it try a connection?

Comment: That's pretty much it, yes. Ports are for associating incoming data with a particular application. If there was only one port on your computer, there could only be one service receiving data at any one time, since nobody would know what program this data is destined for. This works all the way through to the router/firewall level; it needs to know who should receive some incoming data packet. Hence it allocates (opens) temporary ports for outgoing requests, waiting for a response. If you know the randomly chosen port number, you can send data to it.

Comment: Awesome. One last inherent question. In an entirely P2P scenario, say BitTorrent or Bitcoin, once the IP:port have been found through a STUN server, then that peer could become a STUN server itself and help with the hole punching for other peers. Is that the usual scenario?

Comment: Yes, many P2P networks will promote suitable peers to act as relay or perhaps STUN-like servers to strengthen the network.

Comment: Why in the world does WebRTC not use UPnP when doing the STUN stuff? Almost all peers are going to be behind a firewall or NAT. Relaying using TURN is super lame. The folks writing the spec for WebRTC should really consider this!

Answer (score 5):

The original Question is "what/who creates the sockets?"

- The browsers creates the socket and bind them to a local port for you
  during the "ICE gathering".
- Wether you use any stun/turn server or
  not, each candidate generated during the ice gathering has a
  corresponding port open.
- Those ports are usually open only for 30 mn
  after which they are revoked to avoid an attack by someone using old
  and/or spoof candidates. These 30mns are not specified in any
  specification and are an arbitrary choice by the browser vendor. -

The next question is "how does the remote peer know about which ports are open".

- through the ICE mechanism, which for each media will generate potential candidates and send them to the remote peer through your preferred signaling channel.
- ICE candidates (which are one line of SDP, really) have a "type". if this type is HOST, then your candidate is a local candidate generated without the use of any stun or turn server. is the type is SRFLX, then you have used a STUN server to add the mapping between your local IP:port and your public IP:port. if your type is RELAY, same thing with a TURN server.
- of course, using the local IP:port HOST candidate will fail unless the remote peer is on the same local network.
- From the browser and local system point of view, the socket is open on the local IP:PORT anyway. Hence, opening the sockets and finding out on which port a remote peer should connect to connect to the socket are separate problems handled separately.

The Final question is: "can it really work without a STUN server"

- Most probably no, unless you are on the same sub network.
- Stats shows (http://webrtcstats.com) that even with a STUN server, you still fail in 8% of the case, for the general public. It's much more in enterprise, where you'd better have advanced turn (supporting tunneling through TCP/80 and TLS/443) and even support for HTTP proxy's CONNECT method.

Comment: But how do you know about that IP:port without a STUN server? Also, once the IP:port is opened and found, can that IP:port act as another STUN server to help other peers "STUN" their IP:port? Can you do that with WebRTC?